# Is 'the note said' correct?

Tags: grammar

Is 'the note said' correct?
Notes can't speak, so 'the note detailed' might be more correct but doesn't read well in fiction.
So what to use?

For example ('detailed' wouldn't work here):
The note said, 'Please do not read this note.'

Comment: If you don't like "say" because notes can't speak, then you might argue that notes cannot "do" much apart from lying around ...

Comment: ["Your lips say no...but your eyes say yes"](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/35ewzr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb ***[say](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/say)*** is used also with the following sense:

> to give information in writing, numbers, or signs:
>
> - My watch says three o'clock.
> - Can you read what that sign says?

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Usage examples of “the note said”:

From [The Versions of Us](https://books.google.it/books?id=9i7aBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT400&dq=%22the%20note%20said%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr9JH54cT9AhWqgf0HHRz7B-s4ChDoAXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20note%20said%22&f=false) : The Number One bestseller by Laura Barnett 2015:

> We are moving to Canada, the note said. Toronto, we think. Len has a sister there. There is no common ground between us any more, Francis, the note said.

More usage examples  of “[the note said](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20note%20said%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2014,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en#ip=1).” from Google Books